# Limit zoom to button only in leaflet and phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile, leaflet

Is it possible to make it so you can only zoom in and out by using the zoom buttons as opposed to been able to pinch the screen? Perhaps only sensing one touch at a time or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is right there in the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-touchzoom): simply set the map option `touchZoom` to `false` when instantiating the map.

Comment: So do I just write `app.initialize();
   
   touchZoom = false;` Because that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, it's `map.touchZoom.disable();` if anybody else needs it.